# json file line is getting split into half while reading

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I am trying to split json logs using the code below to get an array of each line. Seems like the last line is getting split into half while reading.

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream('web.log', {
        flags: 'r',
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        fd: null,
        mode: '0666',
        bufferSize: 64 * 1024
    });

stream.on('data', function(data){
        fileData += data;

        var lines = fileData.split('\n');
        console.log(lines);
})
```

The log files look like this:

```
{"name":"re","hostname":"DESKTOP","pid":1234,"level":36,"msg":"CHILD::4884","time":"2017-05-26T01:43:07.675Z","src":"","v":5}
{"name":"re","hostname":"DESKTOP","pid":4884,"level":36,"msg":"CHILD::4884","time":"2017-05-26T01:43:07.675Z","src":"","v":5}
```

But the result of the split is like this:

```
[ '{"name":"re","hostname":"DESKTOP","pid":1234,"level":36,"msg":"CHILD::4884","time":"2017-05-26T01:43:07.675Z","src":"","v":5}
',
  '{"name":"re","host' ]
```

Whats going wrong in the code?

Comment: All I can think of is maybe the buffer size? Or not escaping characters correctly, but that's just a shot in the dark O.o

Comment: Yeah even I thought buffer size but unable to find that as an issue. How do I resolve escaping characters issue correctly?

Comment: wherever the data is being inserted, previous to the insertion maybe look into sanitation. If it turns out to even be the problem at all! :)

Comment: Ran your code locally and there was no error at all.. is there more code being executed? what version do you use?

Comment: why you want perform task on string?. you should decode to JSON Object.

Comment: @Kristianmitk the code was working few hours back. So I know you might be right but it doesnt work now. I am using node 8.1.x.

Comment: @Hardeep- I need the string. Let me try decode. Not sure if that will work. But good suggestion.

Comment: @Conor Thompson- thats the issue. You are at the right point there are \\"  but \n Escape strings when I do a console already which is why i want to avoid decode.